# How to find the connection between a radio button and a label?

Tags: html, prototypejs, radio-button, label

I have this label:

```
<label id="options_31409_3label" for="options_31409_3"><span>some text</span></label>
```

As you see, there is some text in the label inside a span. Now I also have a radio button, which is left of the label:

```
<input id="options_31409_3" class="radio" type="radio" value="72058" name="options[31409]" onclick="xyz()">...</input>
```

This is one radio and one label, but I have several radio buttons and labels on the same site. Now from those N labels and radio buttons I have to identify one pair and do some Prototype stuff with it. The pair has a different id each time the site is loaded, the only thing that stays is the text inside the span. Is there a way to get the label and the radiobutton if there is "some text" inside the span? I can use Prototype if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you know that label's id consists of input's id + 'label', you can use e.g. the following code to find a pair:

```
$$('input[type=radio]').each(function() 
    var input = this;
    var label = $(this.id + 'label');
    // do something for input and label
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `label`s `for` attribute, if used correctly, should have the same value as the `input`s `id` attribute. So, you can easily find out which `label` belongs to which `input` like this:

```
$$('label').each(function () {
    var label = this;
    var input = document.getElementById(label.getAttribute('for'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would choose to improve jholser's snippet to work with all labels, not just those that have 'label' in their ID.

```
$$('input[type=radio]').each(function(input) 
{
    // Several labels may link to the same input
    $$('label[for="' + input.identify() + '"]').each(function(label)
    {
        // do something for input and label
    });
});
```